# How to count the number of words in a variable?

Tags: arrays, vb.net

What I want to do is to count the number of words a variable has. It's for a hangman game, and will be separated by commas. So I'm basically hoping that the variable will look something like this:

```
"hang,man,group,toll,snail"
```

I'm planning on splitting it with the commas to create an array, but apart from that, I'm totally lost on what to do.

On the other hand, I'm more than happy to see any other suggestions for sorting out words to be used in a hangman game!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're halfway there.

```
Dim wordCount as Integer = "hang,man,group,toll,snail".Split(",").Length
```

This splits it into an array, and then returns the number of elements in that array.

Answer (score 2):

```
Dim Words as String = "hang,man,group,toll,snail"

Dim Word = Words.Split(",")
```

So the result will be .. Word(0) = "hang", Word(1) = "man" ... so on ..

Answer (score 1):

use Split like so

```
Dim words As String() = SOMESTRING.Split(New Char() {","c})
```

now to find length you can

```
words.length ' set this to a variable or output
```

alternativly you can also use the words individually

```
words(0)     ' set this to a variable or output
words(1)     ' set this to a variable or output
```

and so on

Answer (score 0):

You can easily split a string into an array by using the `String.Split` method.

There are a number of overloads, however the one I use most often is this one:

```
Dim myString as String = "hang,man,group,toll,snail"
Dim myStringArray as String()

myStringArray = myString.Split(new String { "," }, StringSplitOptions.None)
```

This will give you a string array of length 5.

Documentation can be found here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/tabh47cf.aspx

Answer (score 0):

```
Dim Text As String
Dim i As Integer
Dim ary() As String

Text =  "hang,man,group,toll,snail"
ary = Text.Split(",")

For i = 0 To UBound(ary)
    MsgBox(ary(i)) 'here you will get all the words in the array
Next i

MsgBox(i) 'You will get the number of items in your array
```